# I want to put my logs on a separate partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions, log

I want to put my /var/logs on a separate partition.  I know how to fstab, but one thing concerns me...

If I create the partition and mount it to /var/logs what would happen to the data already there... and do I need to worry about the permissions of "anything"?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to delete/move the data in `/var/logs/`.  I don't think you can mount a partition on a folder that has sub-folders or files.

You don't need to worry about permissions, because I think root does all the writing, so it will automatically have permissions. [My `/var/log/` folder permissions are 755, so any user can view, but only the owner (root) can write].

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just all you need to do is create an empty partition and set it's mount point to `/var`.

To do this you must have an USB/DVD Live system and then you can do it with Gparted. after creating the partition on wards all your log data which is a subfolder in `/var` will move into that directory.

Comment: To add information, I'm doing everything from the command like.  I was just concerned about the data already there when I set fstab and reboot.

Comment: That you can move right , simply use sudo mv [source_path] [ Dest_path]